# How can I select what resource files get extracted to the user subdirectory of the installer

Tags: install4j

Is there a way to select what resource files get extracted to the user subdirectory of the installer (within the .install4j) depending on media type. We are currently using install4j 6.0.4 and basically we have one install4j project that builds an exe and rpm. We added some .dlls, .bats, and .exes as resource files for our windows exe but they also get included in the rpm. There are other resource files the exe and rpm share, which is why I'm trying to exclude windows related resource files but keep the common ones. These windows resources files are getting flag by a scanner on linux environments.

I could add the removal of these files in the post install script of the RPM media configuration but whenever the RPM is uninstalled it will always print a warning like so, which isn't desirable.

warning: file /path/to/file: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /path/to/file: remove failed: No such file or directory

Is there a way to select what resource files the RPM will include/exclude or will I need to create a separate install4j projects for my exe and rpm?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional file set in the distribution tree with all files that are only required for Windows.

Then you can exclude that files set in the Linux RPM media wizard under "Customize project defaults->Exclude files".

Comment: Ingo thanks for the quick reply. I can see if we can go this route. Our windows exe does run some actions prior to installing files on the system, which do require certain files to be available in the resource directory (since the actions reference them). I can look to see if we can move these actions to after the installer installs files on the system since they will be available there. From my understanding files in the resource directory are available to the installer prior to files being put on the system for windows.

Comment: That is correct. Unfortunately, there is no option for filtering custom code for media files.